# OpenVPN Cloud for Network monitoring

Tags: monitoring, openvpn, cloud

I'm working on a supervision project based on OpenVPN, a good way to send some network traffic through a secure channel to office from there out to the Internet.
On office i have an OpenVPN server installed and i need to monitor all branches servers that are behind firewalls.
I know that the point to point solution is very easy so we may only install OpenVPN client on node that i need to monitor.
In the fact, is there any other issue that could help to supervise all branches DMZ network, without installing the client on each machines.

http://imagebin.ca/img/SWNToWz.jpg

Comment: Please, explain what are you monitoring... health, logs, services?

Comment: I use nagios, cacti, munin, splunk

Comment: I call "prior art": http://serverfault.com/questions/165448/how-can-i-monitor-remote-customer-windows-linux-pcs-servers-without-opening-a-po/165453#165453  >smile<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate the monitoring from the network access: 
- use openvpn to set up a VPN to give you access to the server side lan
- use a monitoring tool such as Nagios, Ganglia to monitor the remote lan

there is no built-in monitoring in OpenVPN, all it does (and should do) is encrypt and forward traffic.

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful as you will need to configure each openvpn client to start and connect automatically otherwise if the server remotely reboots for windows updates or similar you will loose your connectivity to your remote LAN causing false alerts.